# Will the sever send a 'Server Hello' if ciphers are not negotiated?

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl

I know in Server Hello message, the server chooses the strongest cipher that both the client and server support. If there are no cipher suites that both parties support, the session is ended with a handshake failure alert.

If the ciphers are not supported, will the server still send Server hello message and then there is a handshake failure alert or no Server Hello message is sent by the server.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2):

The server will respond with a handshake failure alert and will **not** send a Server Hello message.

This is clearly spelled out in the [TLS 1.2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.3)